# How to optimize solution to get linear performance to find a histogram's hole total area?

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization

So the problem is, given a histogram find the total area of water that the histogram can hold such that if the histogram was three bars of sizes 5, 3, 5 respectively then the total area of water it can hold is 2 because the histogram can only hold water on top of the 2nd bar (3) since its adjacent bars are larger which forms a hole. Any more than 2, the water would flow off the sides. More examples:

I: [5 2 3 2 4] 
O: 5

I: [2 5 1 4 7 3 1 5 1]
O: (4 + 1) + (2 + 4) = 11
There are holes between bar 2 and bar 5, and between bar 5 and bar 8

My solution is a kind of a brute force solution that takes O(n^2) where for every single bar, you find the min of the max on the right and left side of that bar, and get the difference between that min-max bar and the current bar to get the amount of water that would be held on that one bar. And so on until you go through all the bars.

How would you optimize this to get a linear performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build two array holding the largest element to the left and right of the current one (including itself). You can build each of them in linear time.
For your example:

```
left: [5 5 5 5 5]
right: [5 4 4 4 4]
```

Now run again through the original input and sum `min(left[i], right[i]) - I[i]`. Since now finding the max is just a lookup the entire algorithm is O(N).

You can prove this is correct because for a position i, if you could raise the water level to something higher you would need a barrier to the left and right of at least that level. Since you already use the max from left and max from right there's no barrier higher that what you selected already.

Comment: What I'm wondering is, how would you find that array of the left and right largest elements in linear time? That's what I having trouble with

Comment: @AadeshP Iterate once for left. Iterarate once backwards for right, then iterate once again for the final result. It's still linear even if you iterate a fixed amount of times.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the input array adding every element and its position to a stack. But before adding any element, remove any smaller element before, and compute how much water would fill between z at k and x at i, with a y at j at the bottom.

Please notice that even having to do a loop removing elements from the stack for each element, this would still be O(n), because each element will enter and exit the stack exactly once.

Here's an example Python code:

```py
from collections import deque

def solve(A):
    answer = 0

    Q = deque()
    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        while len(Q) and Q[-1][1] < x:
            j, y = Q.pop()
            if len(Q):
                k, z = Q[-1]
                height = min(x, z) - y
                width = (i - k - 1)
                answer += height * width
        Q.append((i, x))                
    return answer

print solve([2, 5, 1, 4, 7, 3, 1, 5, 1]) #11
print solve([5, 2, 3, 2, 4]) #5
print solve([5, 3, 5]) #2
```